# WP_Query with pagination redirects to homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop, pagination

i have a custom loop for a custom post type set up and also added a pagination. But when the /page/2 is loading it redirects to the homepage. What is causing this?

Here is my code:

```
function viares_graduates () {
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $args = array (
        'paged' => $paged,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'graduates',
        'posts_per_page' => 9, 
        'tag__not_in' => array( '76' ),
        'orderby'        => 'rand',
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
//here my loop is displayed

endwhile;?>
<div class="pagination">
        <?php 
    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
        'total'        => $loop->max_num_pages,
        'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
        'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
        'show_all'     => false,
        'type'         => 'plain',
        'end_size'     => 2,
        'mid_size'     => 1,
        'prev_next'    => true,
        'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', __( 'Newer Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
        'next_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s <i></i>', __( 'Older Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
        'add_args'     => false,
        'add_fragment' => '',
    ) );
        ?>
    </div><?php 
wp_reset_postdata(); 
}
add_shortcode('viares_graduates', 'viares_graduates');
```

The pagination is displayed correctly on the frontend and the loop is working fine. You can check it out here: https://dev.viares.at/graduates/
However when I click on the next page (https://dev.viares.at/graduates/page/2/) it redirects to https://dev.viares.at/

Custom Post Type:

```
function custom_post_type() {
 

    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Graduates', 'Post Type General Name', 'twentytwenty' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Graduate', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'twentytwenty' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Graduates', 'twentytwenty' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Movie', 'twentytwenty' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Graduates', 'twentytwenty' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Graduate', 'twentytwenty' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Graduate', 'twentytwenty' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'twentytwenty' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Graduate', 'twentytwenty' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Graduate', 'twentytwenty' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Graduates', 'twentytwenty' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not Found', 'twentytwenty' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'twentytwenty' ),
    );
     
    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'Graduates', 'twentytwenty' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Reviews from Graduates', 'twentytwenty' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 4,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => false,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'publicly_queryable'  => false,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'taxonomies' => array('post_tag')
 
    );

    register_post_type( 'graduates', $args );
 
}
 
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );
```

Hope anyone can help!

**EDIT/UPDATE:**
I added the shortcode on the page /graduates, which made the error. So I changed the URL slug to /graduate or something else which is not identical to the custom post type name and it works now!

Comment: can you share your config for the custom post type?

Comment: can you add `wp_reset_postdata();` after endwhile

Comment: @JahidHasan tried this and nothing changed

Comment: @mikerojas I added the code to the initial question

Comment: have you tried setting `has_archive` to `true`?  Might need to flush permalinks  too.

Comment: @mikerojas I found the error: I added the shortcode to a page with the slug /graduates. When changing the page to the slug /graduate the pagination works. Also without setting has_archive to true. So I think it has something to do with the custom post type name and the url slug.